# Como obter a cor de um pixel na tela no JAVA 2D game?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Existi alguma maneira de ***Como obter a cor de um Pixel*** nas coordenadas x e y da tela que eu especificar?

Comment: Swing? Android? Browser?

Comment: ops É com a JFrame pra Desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um pouco vaga sua pergunta, mas tente usar:

```
       package teste2;

       import java.awt.Color;
       import java.awt.Robot;

       public class teste {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        Color color = robot.getPixelColor(20, 20);

        System.out.println("Red   = " + color.getRed());
        System.out.println("Green = " + color.getGreen());
        System.out.println("Blue  = " + color.getBlue());
      }



            }
```

Comment: Mas como eu posso imprimir isso? Eu tentei **System.out.println(getPixelColor(100,100));** mas da erro

Comment: Vou fazer um teste aqui. Espera!

Comment: Vê se é isso que você precisa??

Comment: Acredito que colocando as cores com a função Color você irá conseguir através do RGB;